# When is a table not a table?

Tags: meaning, connotation

A desk is a desk, but is there any important difference between the two words for "table"? Here is what the wwwjdic says:

卓 【たく; しょく】table; desk; (たく only) counter for tables, desks

机 【つくえ】 desk

テーブル table

Comment: Main difference is the purpose to use them. You may want to read https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/6285/meaning/m0u/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several common compounds that include 卓 (e.g., 食卓, 卓上, ...), but 卓 as a standalone noun is uncommon. As a starter, you can stick to テーブル in almost all the cases where you want to say *table*.

In modern Japanese, 卓 as a standalone noun is used:

- as part of a few set expressions like 卓を囲む (テーブルを囲む is equally common, though)
- as a rare and highly stiff equivalent of テーブル, when you want to avoid loanwords for some reason
- as jargon meaning "counter" or "booth"; for example, a place like this is sometimes called 卓 in media-related industries:
  [image: 卓]